# Record mb/sec When Writing A File C#

Tags: c#

I have created a method to record the total time it takes to write a file.

How can I extend this to record how many megabytes the method writes per second to my StringBuilder object? I am passing in GB

```
  private string CreateLongRunningDummyFile(int fileSizeGb, string filePath)
        {
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            int fileSizeMb = fileSizeGb * 1024;

            try
            {
                const int blockSize = 1024 * 8;
                const int blocksPerMb = (1024 * 1024) / blockSize;
                byte[] data = new byte[blockSize];
                Random rng = new Random();
                using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
                {
                    // There 
                    for (int i = 0; i < fileSizeMb * blocksPerMb; i++)
                    {
                        rng.NextBytes(data);
                        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                }

                sw.Stop();

                File.Delete(filePath);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                sw.Stop();
            }

            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Elaspsed Time: {0}sec",sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString()));

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: What's not working with what you have?  Be specific.

Comment: How exactly do you want to record this? To your StringBuilder, to the console, to a text file, to the event log, to a database, to a GUI? The idea here is to attempt to solve the problem and ask for help rather than presenting an idea and asking for it to be implemented.

Comment: If it wrote 10mb in 2s, how many mb/s would that be? And how did you work that out? Now just get the computer to do the same thing you did, and you're set.

Comment: You could use a Timer object and raise an event for it each second. Then simply subscribe to the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do some math

```
var rate = fileSizeGb / 1024 / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
```